# Implement Open Shop Scheduling algorithm in glpk (gusek)

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I've tried to implement the 'open shop scheduling' algorithm in gusek usind the following code:

.dat:

```
param endTime := 2809 ;
param nMach := 4 ;
param nJobs := 3 ;

param duration:  
        1    2    3 :=
   1  121  661    6
   2  333  168  489
   3  343  621  212
   4  171  505  324 ;
```

.mod:

```
param endTime integer > 0;
param nMach integer > 0;
param nJobs integer > 0;

param duration {1..nMach, 1..nJobs};

var Start {1..nMach, 1..nJobs} integer >= 0, <= endTime;
var Makespan integer >= 0, <= endTime;

minimize Objective: Makespan;

subject to NoJobConflicts 
      {m in 1..nMach, j1 in 1..nJobs, j2 in j1+1..nJobs}:
   Start[m,j1] + duration[m,j1] <= Start[m,j2]  or
   Start[m,j2] + duration[m,j2] <= Start[m,j1];

subject to NoMachineConflicts 
      {m1 in 1..nMach, m2 in m1+1..nMach, j in 1..nJobs}:
   Start[m1,j] + duration[m1,j] <= Start[m2,j]  or
   Start[m2,j] + duration[m2,j] <= Start[m1,j];

subj to MakespanDefn {m in 1..nMach, j in 1..nJobs}:
   Start[m,j] + duration[m,j] <= Makespan;
```

But i'm getting the following error: "syntax error in constraint statement. Context: ...tart [ m , j1 ] + duration [ m , j1 ] <= Start [ m , j2 ] or ".

As i understood gusek is used for linear problems but operator 'or' is used for non-linear problems.

Is there a way how to solve this problem using gusek.

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constraint like

```
x + a ≤ y  or   
y + b ≤ x
```

can be implemented with a big-M constraint:

```
x + a ≤ y + M⋅δ   
y + b ≤ x + M(1-δ)
δ ∈ {0,1}
```

where `M` is a large enough constant (to be chosen as tight as possible).

So in your case:

```
subject to NoJobConflicts 
      {m in 1..nMach, j1 in 1..nJobs, j2 in j1+1..nJobs}:
   Start[m,j1] + duration[m,j1] <= Start[m,j2] + M*d1[m,j1,j2];

subject to NoJobConflicts2 
      {m in 1..nMach, j1 in 1..nJobs, j2 in j1+1..nJobs}:
   Start[m,j2] + duration[m,j2] <= Start[m,j1] + M*(1-d1[m,j1,j2]) ;
```

`M` can be the length of the planning horizon and `d1` is a binary variable.

Similar for the other case. There you should use a different binary variable. e.g. `d2`.